cant ping through a docker with ns3 emulation process between 2 dockers in different bridge network
I'm trying using a docker with ns-3 emulation process to implement the connection between 2 dockers with different bridge network.
The middle docker uses tap-bridge to connect with outside.
The implement scheme image is given.The implement is almost according to the image except the ip address which is assigned automatically.
implement scheme
First I create 2 bridge nework. Then I create 3 dockers. The left docker is in left-net. The right docker is in right-net. The middle docker is in both network.
After that, I configure the left docker's default route to the middle docker's veth0 address. Also, I configure the middle docker's route to use tap-left to route to left node in ns-3.
left docker's route
middle docker's route
Then I write the ns-3 code to run. I create 2 nodecontainers with 2 nodes respectively.
And I use csma to connect 2 nodes. 2 nodecontainers are in different network. I use global route to connect them. And I also configure the static route of nodes. The left nodes is routed to the right nodes. The right nodes is routed to the tap-right device. Finally, I use tap-bridge with UseBridge mode to connect the tap device and the node.
    NodeContainer nodesRight, nodesLeft;
    nodesRight.Create(2);
    nodesLeft.Create(2);

    CsmaHelper csma;
    NetDeviceContainer devicesRight = csma.Install(nodesRight);
    NetDeviceContainer devicesLeft = csma.Install(nodesLeft);

    Ipv4StaticRoutingHelper ipv4RoutingHelper;

    // for the left net
    InternetStackHelper internetLeft;
    internetLeft.Install(nodesLeft);
    Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4Left;
    ipv4Left.SetBase("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfacesLeft = ipv4Left.Assign(devicesLeft);
    for (auto interface = interfacesLeft.Begin(); interface != interfacesLeft.End(); interface++)
    {
        std::pair<Ptr<Ipv4>, uint32_t> ipv4_device = *interface;
        Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> staticRouting =
            ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting(ipv4_device.first);
        staticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo(Ipv4Address("170.1.8.0"),
                                         Ipv4Mask("255.255.255.0"),
                                         Ipv4Address("10.1.3.2"),  // the right node
                                         ipv4_device.second);
    }

    // for the right net
    InternetStackHelper internetRight;
    internetRight.Install(nodesRight);
    Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4Right;
    ipv4Right.SetBase("10.1.3.0", "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfacesRight = ipv4Right.Assign(devicesRight);
    for (auto interface = interfacesRight.Begin(); interface != interfacesRight.End(); interface++)
    {
        std::pair<Ptr<Ipv4>, uint32_t> ipv4_device = *interface;
        Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> staticRouting =
            ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting(ipv4_device.first);
        staticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo(Ipv4Address("170.1.8.0"),
                                         Ipv4Mask("255.255.255.0"),
                                         Ipv4Address("170.1.8.3"), // the tap-right device
                                         ipv4_device.second);
    }

    TapBridgeHelper tapBridge;
    tapBridge.SetAttribute("Mode", StringValue("UseBridge"));
    tapBridge.SetAttribute("DeviceName", StringValue("tap-left"));
    tapBridge.Install(nodesLeft.Get(0), devicesLeft.Get(0));

    //
    // Connect the right side tap to the right side CSMA device on the right-side
    // ghost node.
    //
    tapBridge.SetAttribute("DeviceName", StringValue("tap-right"));
    tapBridge.Install(nodesRight.Get(0), devicesRight.Get(0));

    Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables();

    Simulator::Stop(Seconds(600.));
    Simulator::Run();
    Simulator::Destroy();

But after I run the code, I am unable to ping the right docker's ip-170.1.8.224.
I use netstat -i to view the middle docker's information for each interface during ping process.
Each interface's information.
I find the tap-left device's amount of sending data is approving. But the tap-right device's data remain. I guess the ns-3 code has problem(maybe static routing). Or maybe the middle docker's route configured has problem.
It's expected I can ping the right docker in left docker through a docker with ns-3 emulation process.
